# Error while connecting tomcat application from redhat to sql server

Tags: sql-server, tomcat, centos7

I have hosted my tomcat application built in Spring Boot to RedHat server. And my SQL Server is installed on Windows Server 2012r2. While running application, I am getting following error:

> 27-May-2019 00:00:04.420 SEVERE [pool-47-thread-1]
>   org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init Unable to create
>   initial connections of pool.
>     com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not
>   establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets
>   Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "Server chose TLSv1, but that protocol
>   version is not enabled or not supported by the client.". .......

I tried installing self signed certificate in RedHat, but no luck.